# Server Error in '/' Application in MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am currently learning MVC 5 by watching video tutorials. I have created one simple customercontroller with two action methods i.e. (AddCustomer and Submit). Here i have created one simple view for AddCustomer and strongly typed view for Showing customer data. When i start application it shows me the customer data entry  screen but when i click on submit button i am getting below error.
Can you please tell me what is the issue in my below code?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Submit
```

Here's my Customer Controller Code:-

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Customer
        public ActionResult AddCustomer()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Submit(Customer objcust)
        {            
            objcust.CustomerID = Request.Form["txtcustid"];
            objcust.CustomerName = Request.Form["txtcustname"];
            return View("ShowCustData", objcust);
        }
    }
```

Here's My ShowCustData View:-

```
@model DataAnnotationsEx.Models.Customer

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ShowCustData</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Customer ID: @Model.CustomerID <br />
        Customer Name: @Model.CustomerName
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's My AddCustomer View:-

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AddCustomer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="Submit" method="post">            
            Customer ID: <input id="Text1" type="text" name="txtcustid" /><br />
            Customer Name: <input id="Text1" type="text" name="txtcustname" /><br />
            <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's My Customer Model:-

```
public class Customer
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(7)]
        [RegularExpression("^[A-Z]{3,3}[0-9]{4,4}$")]
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's My Route.config:-

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Customer", action = "AddCustomer", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Put `[HttpPost]` attribute on top of `Submit` action. At first glance, I see that the form action has `POST` method, hence `[HttpPost]` attribute is mandatory.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks for your quick reply. But its not working. Still showing above error.

Comment: Since this is MVC, you should use `BeginForm` helper with controller name and action name with `FormMethod.Post` parameter - avoid creating `<form>` tag manually.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `Submit` controller action doesn't have `[HttpPost]` attribute, where your form method defined as `POST`. You should add the mentioned attribute on corresponding action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(Customer objcust)
{            
    objcust.CustomerID = objcust.CustomerID;
    objcust.CustomerName = objcust.CustomerName;

    return View("ShowCustData", objcust);
}
```

Note that by default if `[HttpPost]` attribute not specified, it automatically sets as GET method, hence the action method never be reached by form submit request.

Then, you should replace `<form>` tag with `Html.BeginForm()` helper with strongly-typed viewmodel definition like this:

```
@model Customer

@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerID)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerID)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerName)

    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

By using strongly-typed viewmodel class, the textboxes are bound automatically to viewmodel properties and be able to retrieve values during form submission.

Comment: Tetsuya Yamamoto Thanks for your help. I have changed the code according to your recommendation and its working fine now.

Comment: But still i want to know what is the issue in my code. Because in tutorial where tutor is explaining there its working fine but not at my end.

Comment: I had explained that the `[HttpPost]` attribute and `action` attribute path becomes the main issue, because with only "Submit" action name doesn't enough to do submit request, you should add controller name where the action name belongs to. If you check updated code with inspector, you will see the differences clearly.